# Magento not allowing special characters like ä

Tags: php, magento

I uploaded the csv of my products in my magento store. in CSV i am having the product names with special characters like ä . But on the front end those characters are showing some html tags like
"& auml;". I want to avoid such charactres. is there any way to solve the problem.

Thanks...

Comment: Does this happen to products added one by one? I'm guessing magento is using the `html_entites` before output.

Comment: no it is not happening if i add the products one by one manually. not getting why such issue occured

Comment: What its showing on admin product name field.

Comment: in admin also it is showing & auml; instead of ä

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this may it will help you where you want to display product name

```
<?php 

    html_entity_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode(strip_tags($_newProduct['name']))));

   // where $_newProduct is the collection of product
 ?>
```

Or Try something like this

The solution for these problems is to add

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
```

in the .htaccess file in the magento root directory. If you still have problems, ramp up to this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

OR

Go to .htaccess file and remove # from

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

and

open the your csv file in .txt format and Save As under UTF-8 and then import the data in magento

Your special character will also get import in magento admin without any error

hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks For reply. But it doesn't work. Any other solution? or can you tell me how to implement it. i am using this to show the product name on view.phtml <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>

Comment: Hi darshan it is solved. Thanks for your reply. I used only html_entity_decode(); . and it gives me the proper output. Thanks...

Comment: Yes somewhat, i edited the code you provided at first. I just used the first function  html_entity_decode();

Comment: Hello Darshan, Having another trouble with magento. R you there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17537/discussion-between-user1713694-and-darshan-dodiya)

Comment: i have the same problem. but not solved from above solution .my display word is "Careers" in english and it should display in french like "Carrières". i have used <?php echo html_entity_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode(strip_tags($this->__('Careers'))))); ?>  but i am getting output "Carri?s".

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your reply. I used only html_entity_decode(); . and it gives me the proper output. Thanks.

Comment: it's ok always be here if you have any doubts regarding magento